# Qt, QTextStream - inputting a char/string into an int

Tags: c++, qt, qtextstream

Consider the following program:

```
int num;

QTextStream(stdin) >> num;

QTextStream(stdout) << num;
```

Like this, if I am to incorrectly input a string, or a char, into the variable `num`, its value becomes 0 by default.

How can I change the behavior of `QTextStream`, so that it stores a different value for incorrect inputs? For example, -1?

Comment: You could subclass QTextStream and overrload the operator>>(int).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot change this behavior, but you can check `QTextStream::status()` for `QTextStream::ReadCorruptData`.

```
int num;

QTextStream input(stdin);
input >> num;

if (input.status() == QTextStream::ReadCorruptData)
    num = -1;

QTextStream(stdout) << num;
```